# Theoretical clarification regarding maps and iterators

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

If I have a class with a map as a private member such as

```
class MyClass
{
  public:
    MyClass();
    std::map<std::string, std::string> getPlatforms() const;
  private:
    std::map<std::string, std::string> platforms_;
};

MyClass::MyClass()
        :
{
  platforms_["key1"] = "value1";
  // ...
  platforms_["keyN"] = "valueN";
}

std::map<std::string, std::string> getPlatforms() const
{
  return platforms_;
}
```

And in my main function would there be a difference between these two pieces of code?

Code1:

```
MyClass myclass();
std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator definition;
for (definition = myclass.getPlatforms().begin();
     definition != myclass.getPlatforms().end();
     ++definition){
  std::cout << (*definition).first << std::endl;
}
```

Code2:

```
MyClass myclass();
std::map<std::string, std::string> platforms = myclass.getPlatforms();
std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator definition;
for (definition = platforms.begin();
     definition != platforms.end();
     ++definition){
  std::cout << (*definition).first << std::endl;
}
```

In Code2 I just created a new map variable to hold the map returned from the getPlatforms() function.

Anyway, in my real code (which I cannot post the real code from but it is directly corresponding to this concept) the first way (Code1) results in a runtime error with being unable to access memory at a location.

The second way works!

Can you enlighten me as to the theoretical underpinnings of what is going on between those two different pieces of code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getPlatforms()` returns the map by value, rather than reference, which is generally a bad idea.

You have shown one example of why it is a bad idea:

`getPlatforms().begin()` is an iterator on a map that is gone before the iterator is used and `getPlatforms().end()` is an iterator on a different copy from the same original map.

Comment: As Joe pointed out getPlatforms() is const, so returning the map by non const reference would be a problem.  (Returning by value from a const method is no problem, but as I tried to explain, returning by value is a bad idea).  So you want to return by `const&` in which case what Joe said about const_iterator would become correct.

Comment: Thank you.  A few followup questions if you don't mind: (1) How do return a map by reference? (2) When is it better to return an object by reference vs by value?

Comment: Instead of `std::map<std::string, std::string> getPlatforms() const;` you use `std::map<std::string, std::string> const& getPlatforms() const;` then you need to switch to a const_iterator for your code1.

Comment: For code2 to be comparable to the corrected code1, you would make the two changes described in the above comment and also change `std::map<std::string, std::string> platforms = myclass.getPlatforms();` into std::map<std::string, std::string> const& platforms = myclass.getPlatforms();`

Comment: It is almost always better to return any lasting large object by `const&` rather than by value.  Then the caller can decide whether to take it by `const&` or make a copy by taking it by value.  If you want to expose the internal member to outside modification, then return it by `&` instead of `const&`

Comment: @NathanOliver Move semantics rarely apply to pure member-access getters. It is seldom you'd want to *move* a member data structure out of an object.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you enlighten me as to the theoretical underpinnings of what is going on between those two different pieces of code?

When you return by value, you return a deep copy of the data.

When you call `myclass.getPlatforms().begin();` and `myclass.getPlatforms().end();` you are effectively constructing two copies of your data, then getting the begin iterator from one copy and the end iterator from the other. Then, you compare the two iterators for equality; **This is undefined behavior**.

> results in a runtime error with being unable to access memory at a location.

This is because `definition` is initialized, then the temporary object used to create it is deleted, invalidating the data the iterator pointed to. Then, you attempt to use the data, through the iterator.

Answer (score -2):

A problem that you have is that you should be using `const_iterator` not `iterator`. This is because the function `getPlatforms` is `const` qualified, whereas the function in the map `iterator begin()` is not; you must use the `const` qualified `const_iterator begin() const` instead to explicitly tell the compiler you will not modify any members of the class.

Note: this is only the case for code 1, which should, by the way return `const&`

Comment: Wrong. The return value of `getPlatforms()` is *not* `const`-qualified, so it is perfectly possible to use mutating iterators with it.

Comment: @AngeW - sorry I forgot to clarify that it only occurs with `const&` return type

Comment: `const` is not the problem.  They have an iterator to an object that no longer exist.

Comment: @NathanOliver - but if you return by `const&`, code 1 compiles and run just like how code 2 would

Comment: @Joe **[Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)** can still work.  See: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8d947be3968933e

Comment: @NathanOliver - sorry I thought for some reason that codes 1 and 2 were member functions of `myclass` in which case if the functions were `const` qualified, `const_iterator` would be required. My bad

Comment: @Joe the OP has `And in my main function would there be a difference between these two pieces of code?`