# iterator loses its value - simple short loop c++

Tags: c++, loops, iterator

here's this simple loop of code:

```
std::list<Worker*>::const_iterator checkSecond;
std::list<Worker*>::const_iterator workitt;

int i=0;
for (checkSecond=toCheck.getWorkersInMovie().begin(); i != 
toCheck.getNumOfWorkers(); ++checkSecond)
{
    cout<< "id of check is:" << endl;
    cout<<(*checkSecond) ->getId()<<endl; PRINTS 2, AS EXPECTED
    //toChecking = (*checkSecond);

    i++;
    int j=0;
    for (workitt=toReturn.getWorkersInMovie().begin(); j!= 
    toReturn.getNumOfWorkers(); ++workitt)
    {
        cout<< "ids are:" << endl;
        cout<< (*workitt)-> getId() << endl; PRINTS 24, AS EXPECTED
        cout<< (*checkSecond)->getId()<<endl; ALSO PRINTS 24
    }
  }

 list<Worker*> Movie::getWorkersInMovie() const{

return workersInMovie;

}
```

i dont get it, why would checkSecond lose its value?
getWorkersInMovie returns by Value.

HELP..?

Comment: Does `whatever::getWorkersInMovie()` return by value?

Comment: yes, just editted so you can see

Comment: The point LogicStuff was making is that return by value is a mistake for that function.  You can't use iterators on a temporary object created by return by value (beyond the life of that temporary object).  My own more detailed answer (to a previous occurance of this same question) appears here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32202959/theoretical-clarification-regarding-maps-and-iterators/32203052#32203052

Comment: I see what you say, but how do i return by reference? when i change the syntax to list::<Worker*> & the program doesnt compile

Comment: As discussed in the comments of that other answer, you can't return by `&` from a `const` function.  You can return by `const&` if you only need read access to the underlying data.  But if you want to expose the underlying data to outside modification, the function should not be `const`

Comment: I think you don't want to expose the contents to outside modification, so I think you want `list<Worker*> const& Movie::getWorkersInMovie() const` and remember that must match between the declaration and definition.

Comment: dude you're right! tryng to give u some reputation but can't.. could you tell me why this one worked..?

Comment: I don't know which aspect of this you don't understand yet:  1) You need to return by reference rather than value, so you aren't making and immediately destroying a temporary copy of the object.  2) That needs to be a `const&` if you are returning it from a `const` function, because a `const` function has only `const` access to the members of its object.  Did you read the answer and associated comments I linked to above?  They might help clear up whatever is still confusing you.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Movie::getWorkersInMovie()` returns a copy of some list by value and you cannot acquire iterators from that copy.

Your code has undefined behavior, since the list goes out of scope after the assignment to the iterator and the iterator becomes invalid.

`Movie::getWorkersInMovie()` looks like it should return a reference-to-const:

```
list<Worker*> const& Movie::getWorkersInMovie() const;
```

**However**, you can iterate on an rvalue container with range-based for loop:

```
for(auto const& x : toCheck.getWorkersInMovie())
{
    ...
}
```

This temporary will be destructed when the loop exits.

Comment: trying to correct your answer.. you said workitt iterates over toCheck, which is not what happens